# Android Studio crashes on every git commit

Tags: android, git, android-studio

So, I imported a reasonably large android app project including a few library projects from eclipse into android studio.

Everything works fine, except that, after i added git via the vcs menu, added all the files to git, android studio completely freezes as soon as i try to commit any changes made. The only way to get back working is to force quit android studio and reopen it.

I am working on mac OSX. The git commit via command line works like a charm, only android studio is mocking. Any ideas why this could be the case?

Edit: Android studio version was 1.5, now updated to 1.5.1, still the same problem

Comment: It seem's that you're not alone https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183953